# Exception on updating :

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

```
org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count 
from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1
```

I have this exception when i want to update my object, here is my code :

```
public void addProject(Projet projet) {
    Session session =  HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    session.save(projet);
    session.getTransaction().commit(); 
}
    @Override
public void editProject(Projet projet) {
    Session session =  HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    session.update(projet);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

The controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value="/pages/addProjet")
public String addProjet(Model model,@RequestParam String nomProjet, @RequestParam String idProjet, @RequestParam String descProjet){
    Projet projet = new Projet();
    System.out.println("id : " +idProjet);
    if(""==idProjet){
    projet.setNomProjet(nomProjet);
    projet.setEnCours(1); 
    projet.setDescription(descProjet);
    projetService.addProject(projet);
    }else{
        projet.setNomProjet(nomProjet);
        projet.setEnCours(1); 
        projet.setDescription(descProjet);
        projetService.editProject(projet); 
    }

    return "redirect:/pages/index.htm";
}
```

When i write the try catch to handle the exception, and close the session on the finally section, it made **another exception** that says `session was already closed.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe one of the following will solve your problem

**StaleStateException**  is caused by several things:

1. Flushing the data before committing the object may lead to clear all
   object pending for persist.
2. If object has primary key which is auto generated and you are
   forcing an assigned key
3. if you are cleaning the object before committing the object to
   database.
4. Zero or Incorrect ID: If you set the ID to zero or something else,
   Hibernate will try to update instead of insert.
5. Object is Stale: Hibernate caches objects from the session. If the
   object was modified, and Hibernate doesn’t know about it, it will
   throw this exception — note the StaleStateException

More details can be obtained from [org.hibernate.StaleStateException](http://java-fp.blogspot.co.uk/2011/09/orghibernatestalestateexception-batch.html)

**session was already closed Exception** is caused  as  You're using lazily fetching in a session scoped managed bean while the Hibernate session is based on request. have a look at [Session is already closed](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t20533.html)